# Sharepoint Custom List conditional formatting date comparison

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, xslt-list-view-web-part, formatting, conditional

I am having an issue when creating conditional formatting using SharePoint Designer 2010. When the `@Complete_x0020_Date` is less than or equal to `@Negotiated_x0020_Date`, it will color the `@Complete_x0020_Date` cell green.

I have used the conditional formatting task pain to create this however it never works. Below is what was generated.

```
<xsl:if test="ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string($thisNode/@Complete_x0020_Date))) &lt;= normalize-space(@Negotiated_x0020_Date)" ddwrt:cf_explicit="1">background-color: #00FF00;</xsl:if>
```